# Mercury editor not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I save something like 'Lorem ipsum', that's what appears after refresh:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess RandomPageName: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess type: full data: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {} value: lorem ipsum snippets: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}
```

everything is default.

The github repo is here:
https://github.com/gwuix2/gerse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format in which mercury editor sends params is a little different. Some what like this

```
{"content"=>{"title"=>{"type"=>"simple", "data"=>{}, "value"=>"Hello world"}}
```

So normal @post.update_attributes(params[:post]) wont work.

You could write a private method like

```
def extract_params(params)
  attr = {}
  params[:content].each { |key, value| attr[key.to_sym] = value['value'] }
  attr
end
```

and then call @post.update_attributes(extract_params(params))

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure take a look at the documentation for Mercury. https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury

There is also a pretty good railscast on this http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor, it's a bit old so you will have to use the documentation for updated changes. One of the primary changes are that regions are initialized differently in the most current version.

```
<div id="primary" data-mercury="full">
```

vs

```
 <div id= "primary" class="mercury-region" data-type="editable">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see a better screen cast here : : :

```
<http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=mercury>
```